# Unable to pass NULL pointer to array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nodeWords
{
    char * word;
    int    index;
    struct nodeWords *left;
    struct nodeWords *right;
} nodeWords;

int main(void)
{

    nodeWords * node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    printf("%lu\n",sizeof(*node));
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;

    nodeWords  * ihash = malloc(2 * sizeof(*ihash));        
    printf("%p \n", node->left); 

    //this part not working   
    ihash[0] = *node->left;
    printf("%p\n",ihash[0]);

}
```

How can I assign `node->left` to `ihash[0]` and then be able to print out `ihash[0]`, which should point to `NULL`?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. `ihash[0]` is a struct. There's no such thing as a NULL struct. Not entirely sure what you are trying to do. Perhaps you want `ihash` to be an array of struct pointers instead? `nodeWords  **ihash = malloc(2 * sizeof(*ihash)); ihash[0] = node->left;`?

Comment: So `ihash[0]` should itself be a pointer, right? In your code, it's the struct `nodeWords`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two *errors* in your code and a few other 'minor issues' (I've commented these in the code posted below).

The first error is that you want to create an array of **pointers** to `nodeWords`, so you will need **two** stars in the declaration of `ihash` (one star will create an array of structure *objects*).

Second, in `ihash[0] = *node->left;`, you are dereferencing `node` **twice** (once with the preceding star operator, and once again with the `->` operator.

The following code fixes these issues:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nodeWords {
    char* word;
    int    index;
    struct nodeWords* left;
    struct nodeWords* right;
} nodeWords;

int main(void)
{

    nodeWords* node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(*node)); // Should really use "%zu" for size_t 
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;

    nodeWords** ihash = malloc(2 * sizeof(*ihash)); // You want an array of POINTERS so you need two ** in the type!
    printf("%p \n", (void*)node->left); // Pedantic: %p expects a void*

    //this part not working   
    ihash[0] = node->left; // The "*" preceding "node" was an error: the "->" inherentlt derefernces node
//  ihash[0] = (*node).left; // An alternative way of dong the same thing
    printf("%p\n", (void*)ihash[0]); // Pedantic: %p expects a void*

    // Don't forget to free the allocated memory...
    free(ihash);
    free(node);

    return 0; // Always good practice to put this EXPLICIT return statement in your "main"
}
```

Comment: does nodeWords** mean a pointer to an array of pointers or is there some other way I should think about the double **

Comment: @DCR If you have something like `int* ptr = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));` then `ptr` will be a pointer to a block of memory that can be treated like an array of `int` objects. Adding the extra star, like `int** ptr2 = malloc(5 * sizeof(int*));` makes `ptr2` an 'array' of `int*` objects - or an 'array' of pointers-to-ints. It is similar in your case. (Does this make sense?)

Comment: @DCR Maybe it is clearer writing with different spacing, like: `nodeWords* *ihash = malloc...` ?

Comment: so with one * and malloc we get a block of memory that can be treated like an array and would hold objects of some type and with two * we get a block of memory that will hold an array of pointers - and each of those pointers point to a block of memory that holds some type of object.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @DCR Almost! But *and each of those pointers point to a block of memory that holds some type of object* will **only** be true once you have ***explicitly*** set each to point to valid memory.